# Make one space after every comma?

Tags: linux, sed

In Linux, using sed.. how can I make sure that every comma is followed by only one space?

(If there is no space, then add a space after the comma. If there is more than 1 space after the comma, then trim it back so there is only 1.)

I've tried Googling for a solution, but haven't been able to find anything.

Comment: Do you want to trim multiple spaces after a comma to one space, or do you want to add a space in case there is none? Or both?

Comment: I want to do both. If there is no space, then add a space after the comma. If there is more than 1 space after the comma, then trim it back so there is only 1.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to make sure that there is exactly one space after every comma, you can use:

```
sed 's/, */, /g' file
```

Call it as follows to do the substitution directly in the file instead of only printing it:

```
sed -i 's/,/, /g; s/,\s\+/, /g' file
```

Comment: This seems to of done the trick. Thank you, and thanks for the explanation too so I understand.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
sed 's/, */, /g' filename
```

Comment: Hmm, I ran this in UXTerm on Ubuntu.. and it printed back to the console the contents of my test.txt, and it fixed the comma spacing. But how can I get it to automatically save it/fix it in test.txt?

Comment: Add option `-i`: `sed -i 's/, */, /g' filename`

Answer (score 0):

With GNU sed:

`sed -re 's/,/, /g' -i your_file`

- `-i your_file`: The file to edit